# Check Checkboxes based on values in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Checkbox check with Array or values

**Html Code:**

```
<div id="weekdays">
<label for="saturday">  Saturday    </label><input type='checkbox' name='week_day[]' value='saturday'  id="saturday">   
<label for="sunday">    Sunday      </label><input type='checkbox' name='week_day[]' value='sunday'    id="sunday"> 
<label for="monday">    Monday      </label><input type='checkbox' name='week_day[]' value='monday'    id="monday"> 
<label for="tuesday">   Tuesday     </label><input type='checkbox' name='week_day[]' value='tuesday'   id="tuesday">    
<label for="wednesday"> Wednesday   </label><input type='checkbox' name='week_day[]' value='wednesday' id="wednesday">  
<label for="thursday">  Thursday    </label><input type='checkbox' name='week_day[]' value='thursday'  id="thursday">   
<label for="friday">    Friday      </label><input type='checkbox' name='week_day[]' value='friday'    id="friday">
```

**Array**

```
var f = ["saturday", "sunday", "monday"]
```

**info**
I wanna check the days saturday, sunday and monday on this form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the forEach method of Array this is very simple even without JQuery.

```
f.forEach(function(i){
  document.getElementById(i).checked = true;
});
```

You can read more about for each on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: i try it into modal form it not working , do you have any idea ?
info : i use jqueryUi

Comment: happy to take a look if you are still having trouble, would you like to throw a fiddle together?

Comment: What if my array changed??? For example i am getting this array with a button click and just think array items change randomly. How to uncheck other checkboxes??

Comment: if you're wanting to un-check boxes you'll want to iterate over each time and assign checked to true/false based on if its in the new array.

Answer (score 6):

A jQuery selector is nothing but a string, so just join the array into a string of ID's :

```
$('#'+f.join(', #')).prop('checked', true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K7VpC/)

Comment: Shouldnt the comma be before the `#`?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - yes it should, just realized it myself.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is iterate over the array and use `prop` method along with id selector.

```
for(var i=0;i<f.length;i++) {
    $('#' + f[i]).prop('checked', true)
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9bN6/)**

Comment: I think you meant `true` not `false`?