# How to check off checkboxes based on array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I really need your help and I couldn't seem to find a similar solution out there that would provide the support I needed for what I am trying to accomplish here.

How can I programmatically check off the following check boxes based on their values in an array.

```
var arr = ['recurr_date2','recurr_date4']
```

I'd like to check the checkbox whose value is recurr_date2 and recurr_date4

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<input name="recurr_target" value="recurr_date2" type="checkbox">
<input name="recurr_target" value="recurr_date3" type="checkbox">
<input name="recurr_target" value="recurr_date4" type="checkbox">
```

I am fine with an anwer also using jQuery

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537579/check-checkboxes-based-on-values-in-an-array

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `filter` to check the value of your input if it is in array or not.

```js
var arr = ['recurr_date2', 'recurr_date4'];

$("input[name='recurr_target']").filter(function() {
  return arr.indexOf(this.value) != -1;
}).prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="recurr_target" value="recurr_date2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="recurr_target" value="recurr_date3" type="checkbox" />
<input name="recurr_target" value="recurr_date4" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: `return $(this);` is weird. Why go through the trouble of creating a new jquery object just to convert said object to a boolean value

Comment: filter expects a boolean value to be returned. If you return something else, it will be converted to a boolean. You very well could have just returned the conditional without the if statement. it's redundant. `if(true) return true;` -> `return true`

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
var arr = ['recurr_date2','recurr_date4']
arr.forEach(function(ar){
  if(!$('input[value='+ar+']').prop('checked'))//see if its unchecked
    $('input[value='+ar+']').click()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = ['recurr_date2','recurr_date4']
for(let name of arr) {
  document.querySelector(`[value="${name}"]`).setAttribute('checked', '')
}
```

Here's what that does:

1. Iterate over the list of checkboxes to tick off
2. Get the DOM element for it
3. Add the `checked` attribute